# "need not to be neither atomic nor ordered"

Tags: grammar

Is this double/triple negative grammatically sound?

Ordered operations require that space on disk is allocated sequentially, so spatial ordering corresponds to chronology of operations, but actual disk writes **need not to be neither atomic nor ordered.**

Explanation:

Words *neither* and *nor* emphasize on the fact that both conditions are (independently) allowed to remain unsatisfied, that both are optional. To be more formal, "**need not be atomic and need not be ordered**". But then again, it becomes a concoction of two negations joined by a conjunction.

Comment: No. "...need not be atomic or ordered."

Comment: You don't need the first 'not'.   "actual disk writes need to be neither atomic nor ordered."

Comment: In the context of your writing (explaining the rules of disk writes) - _actual disk writes must not be atomic or ordered._

Comment: @James- I think *must* is a bit strong.  It's not that they mustn't be, it's just that they don't need to be.

Comment: @James - The original doesn't imply that anything *must* be true.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - That's what I come up with too, but it's not particularly satisfying.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood completely.  It's much clearer now.  "disk writes need be neither atomic nor ordered" because both are optional.

Comment: @Jim: wouldn't "need not be atomic nor ordered" also work? That's what I first thought of.

Answer (score 1):

No. The sentence as written is over-negated. You can't use "not" and "neither" together; you want "not... either."

---

"Need not to be" is also grammatically incorrect.

We can say "don't need to be." The uncontracted equivalent of that would be "do not need to be." You need to use the auxiliary "do" because it is negative.

If you don't include "do," you can use a separate construction, "need not be," where "need" functions a bit like an auxiliary. In this construction, you do not include "to" before the infinitive.

Comment: I appreciate the theoretic explanation but I dont know how to put that all into a full sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As with most Boolean expressions, you can factor this out to be:

> Ordered operations require that space on disk is allocated
>   sequentially, so that spatial ordering corresponds to the chronology
>   of operations, but actual disk writes **need not be either atomic or
>   ordered.**