# British English / a strange way of using neither nor

Tags: neither-nor

I am not a native English speaker , so I am sorry if there is any grammatical mistakes. I wanted to ask how correct the following sentence is

> This game isn't good neither for children nor for adults.

I tried to find the answer on google but to no avail.
Please if anybody has any idea about that sentence, don't hold back, help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["need not to be neither atomic nor ordered"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285005/need-not-to-be-neither-atomic-nor-ordered) (the use of neither ... nor after a negated verb).

Comment: Yes It is so close to what I needed to know ، heartfelt thanks

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Please read the label. Try English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Englishes don't allow negative polarity words (*none*, *nowhere*, *never*, *neither*) to be used with explicit negation (*not*, *isn't*).

So your sentence is not grammatical in any standard English. The negative may either be in the verb:

> This game isn't good either for children or for adults.

or in the complement:

> This game is good neither for children nor for adults.

but not both.

[Many people throughout the English-speaking world speak varieties which *do* allow so-called "double negatives", and your example would be grammatical in one of those varieties. But not in any Standard English]

Comment: How about splitting the sentence, to provide some emphasis in a second clause? "This game isn't good, neither for children nor for adults."

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Indeed. My first thought on reading OP's example "sentence" was *That sequence is fine - but it should be written as **two** sentences*. If I consider the sequence *It's not very wet outside today. Not for ducks, anyway*, it seems to me it's completely arbitrary whether to repeat ***not*** in the second element (which I hesitate to call a proper "sentence" anyway). But I completely agree with Colin's analysis here if we forget about such "fragmentary" utterances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would be helpful to know the home language.  The reinforcing double negative is common in most (I think) romance languages and in modern Greek.  Many English dialects make wise use of such reinforcement, albeit not for the disjunction.

Comment: @Tuffy: I think it's much more widespread than that. Certainly Russian, for example. The most relevant chapter in [WALS](https://wals.info/chapter/115) shows 170 cases of "predicate negation also present" (i.e. "double negative") against 11 of "no predicate negation". It lists English as "mixed", because there is a distinct set of indefinite pronouns for negative sentences ("anything" vs "something" etc).

Comment: @Tuffy: I think Colin's *not grammatical in any standard English* is perfectly true (more than that, I trust him to be more knowledgeable about *formal rules* of English syntax than I am, *and* more likely to know *specific varieties* of "non-standard English" that break this rule). But the OP here isn't asking *How **common** is this?* (Answer, *It's **very uncommon** among Anglophones at large*). The question is *How **correct** is this?* (Answer, *Ignoring contrived contexts, it's **totally incorrect** in "standard English"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: (Sorry, I don't know how to reply on my laptop!).  I realise I am pushing usage to the limit, and you are trained in linguistics, where I am only a classicist.  However, it seems to me that non-standard is not the same as ungrammatical.  So Samuel Beckett can open his 'Murphy' with:  "The sun was shining, having no alternative, on the nothing new."  Non-standard this brilliantly is, but in a deliberate and brilliant manner that stops us in our tracks and create bathos.  But is it really 'ungrammatical'?

Comment: @Tuffy: I'm not really "trained" in linguistics. All I really remember from the one-year course 50 years ago was a lot of guff about Noam Chomsky's theory of "Universal Grammar". I never believed in it anyway, and my understanding is it's  been increasingly increasingly debunked (having been if anything *unhelpful* in the task of getting machines to understand natural language). I like that Beckett quote, but my guess is it's really a "use/mention" distinction. Since there *is* X under the sun, the sun can shine on X (where  X =  "nothing new"). A sort of "syntactic parody".